# The Software request MS Excel

Tags: excel

I have one system that will request MS Excel to generate some xlsx file.
but unfortunately I don't have MS Excel and actually, I cannot install Ms Office.
How can I get this work and without install MS Excel?

Comment: Use LibreOffice https://www.libreoffice.org/

Comment: I found that it was Office 365 issue because the 365 version is run as a cloud server so without local library Excel.Application.
HOW TO GET Excel.Application IN LOCAL?